# How do I prevent the system command in Perl from executing any shell commands?

Tags: perl

How do I prevent the system command in Perl from executing any shell commands?

Comment: If your purpose in asking this is about security, make sure to consider `qx` and `exec` as well.  And you may find some answers in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html - though that explains how to call `system` safely, not how to prevent something from calling `system` or to prevent `system` from doing something.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) to run shell commands, don't use `system` because that's what it is there to do.

If you're talking about running only the commands that you want to run, there are various ways around that. I talk about some of them in *Mastering Perl*'s security chapter. However, you'll have to clarify what problems you are trying to avoid.

Comment: sorry what exactly i meant was that i need to allow some commands but not all of them

Answer (score 2):

Require them to be found in the path. Executables on the path are not shell commands.

Comment: That is, until someone inserts a shell script into one of the directories. Merely requiring it to be in the PATH is just a speedbump.

Comment: @brian, well he didn't mention why he didn't want to run shell commands, so I had to back-fill there. One of the reasons I came up with is that shell commands might fail on a given platform because they only are valid within a shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can mock `system` by setting up an alias to `CORE::GLOBAL::system`:

```
BEGIN {
    *CORE::GLOBAL::system = \&mock_system;
}

sub mock_system {
    my @cmd = @_;
    if ("@cmd" eq "/bin/ls /tmp") {
        return CORE::system(@cmd);
    } else {
        warn "You may only use 'system' to list the /tmp directory";
        return 256;
    }
}
```

This wouldn't protect you from somebody explicitly calling `CORE::system`, though.